# Using Stateful React classes in typescipt

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a Stateful class in which you can call methods such as `createHeaderButton()` where after calling it would update the state and re-render with these new updates in the component.

Im using Material-UI and so most of their styling utilizes Reacts hook API which of course classes cant use. Ive tried to get around this by using;

```
export default withStyles(useStyles)(HeaderBar)
```

Which exports the class separately with the Styles(`withStyles(useStyles)` useStyles as the defined styles) And the class(`HeaderBar`). Now the only issue is that i need to access the styles in my class.  Ive found a JS example online that wont work for me because of the strong typed syntax of TS. Additionally When initializing my Class component in other places i try to get the `ref=(ref:any)=>{}` And with that call the create button methods when i get a response from my server, Which doesnt work because of this new way of exporting the class component!

Thanks for the help, Heres my component class: https://pastebin.pl/view/944070c7
And where i try to call it: https://pastebin.com/PVxhKFHJ

Comment: Honestly I would convert this to a function component.  The way that you are using a public class method to insert buttons from outside of the class doesn't feel right.  `barButtons` should be a prop (which would be stateful in `Layout`) and `HeaderBar` shouldn't have any state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal opinion is that you should convert `HeaderBar` to a function component.  The reason that it needs to be a class right now is so you can use a ref to call a class method to modify the buttons.  But this is not a good design to begin with.  Refs should be avoided in cases where you can use props instead.  In this case, you can pass down the buttons as a prop.  I think the cleanest way to pass them down is by using the special `children` prop.

Let's create a `BarButton` component to externalize the rendering of each button.  This is basically your `this.state.barButtons.forEach` callback, but we are moving it outside of the `HeaderBar` component to keep our code flexible since the button doesn't depend on the `HeaderBar` (the header bar depends on the buttons).

What is a bar button and what does it need?  It needs to have a `label` text and a `callback` function which we will call on click.  I also allowed it to pass through any valid props of the material-ui `Button` component.  Note that we could have used `children` instead of `label` and that's just down to personal preference.

You defined your `ButtonState` as a callback which takes the `HTMLButtonElement` as a prop, but none of the buttons shown here use this prop at all.  But I did leave this be to keep your options open so that you have the possibility of using the button in the callback if you need it.  Using `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target` gets the right type for the element.

```
import Button, {ButtonProps as MaterialButtonProps} from "@material-ui/core/Button";

type ButtonState = (button: HTMLButtonElement) => void;

type BarButtonProps = {
  label: string;
  callback: ButtonState;
} & Omit<MaterialButtonProps, 'onClick'>

const BarButton = ({ label, callback, ...props }: BarButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <Button 
      color="inherit" // place first so it can be overwritten by props
      onClick={(e) => callback(e.currentTarget)}
      {...props}
      >
      {label}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

Our HeaderBar becomes a lot simpler.  We need to render the home page button, and the rest of the buttons will come from `props.childen`.  If we define the type of `HeaderBar` as `FunctionComponent` that includes `children` in the props (through a `PropsWithChildren<T>` type which you can also use directly).

Since it's now a function component, we can get the CSS classes from a material-ui hook.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: 0
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1
  }
});

const HeaderBar: FunctionComponent = ({ children }) => {

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <HeaderMenu classes={classes} />
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            <BarButton
              callback={() => renderModule(<HomePage />)}
              style={{ color: "white" }}
              label="Sundt Memes"
            />
          </Typography>
          {children}
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Nothing up to this point has used state at all, `BarButton` and `HeaderBar` are purely for rendering.  But we do need to determine whether to display "Log In" or "Log Out" based on the current login state.

I had said in my comment that the buttons would need to be stateful in the `Layout` component, but in fact we can just use state to store an `isLoggedIn` `boolean` flag which we get from the response of `AuthVerifier` (this could be made into its own hook).  We decide which buttons to show based on this `isLoggedIn` state.

I don't know what this `handle` prop is all about, so I haven't optimized this at all.  If this is tied to `renderModule`, we could use a state in `Layout` to store the contents, and pass down a `setContents` method to be called by the buttons instead of `renderModule`.

```
interface LayoutProp {
  handle: ReactElement<any, any>;
}

export default function Layout(props: LayoutProp) {
  // use a state to respond to an asynchronous response from AuthVerifier
  // could start with a third state of null or undefined when we haven't gotten a response yet
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  // You might want to put this inside a useEffect but I'm not sure when this
  // needs to be re-run. On every re-render or just once?
  AuthVerifier.verifySession((res) => setIsLoggedIn(res._isAuthenticated));

  return (
    <div>
      <HeaderBar>
        {isLoggedIn ? (
          <BarButton
            label="Log Out"
            callback={() => new CookieManager("session").setCookie("")}
          />
        ) : (
          <>
            <BarButton
              label="Log In"
              callback={() => renderModule(<LogInPage />)}
            />
            <BarButton
              label="Sign Up"
              callback={() => renderModule(<SignUpPage />)}
            />
          </>
        )}
      </HeaderBar>
      {props.handle}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I believe that this rewrite will allow you to use the material-ui styles that you want as well as improving code style, but I haven't actually been able to test it since it relies on so many other pieces of your app.  So let me know if you have issues.

Comment: Great thanks! I changed by design around a bit, The reason i was calling the ref is because the adding of the Buttons(BarButtons) was going to be async. And looking at your end example wouldnt work because of the Sync code and that i dont have the `isLoggedIn` When initializing the component.

Otherwise great response, Thanks!

Comment: In order to properly handle the async login you can have three states of `isLoggedIn`: maybe `null`, `true`, and `false`?  It would first render with the `null` case and then update to either the `true` or the `false` case after the `async` code has finished and called `setIsLoggedIn` to the new value.  The component will re-render as soon as the logged-in state has changed.